# Access outside parameter in SetState function

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to access onClick parameter inside setState function.

```
   const [tableData, settableData] = useState({ tableDataList: [] });
   
   const deleteRow = (rowId) => {
        settableData(tData => {
         //I have to access rowId to delete row with rowid from tData here
            return tData;
        });
    }
```

.
.

```
      //This button is inside a table. Present in all rows
      <button className="btn-dark" onClick={() => deleteRow(rowId)}>DELETE</button>
```

Can any one help me to access rowId inside setState function?

Comment: How do you know you cannot access it. What error are you getting?

Comment: @TusharShahi undefined

Comment: Can you show where rowId is defined? Also More code showing the table rows

Comment: @TusharShahi rowId is accessible outside settableData(), but not accessible inside it

Comment: See it might have to do with closures. Or might be that the value of rowId is being updated later. Or something else itself. If you add your code it will be easier for everyone to find that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter out using normal array methods from JavaScript. One example is [the filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that helps you filter the array based on how you like it to be filtered.

The following example will filter the array, returning all items, except for the item that matches the rowId, returning a new array without the deleted item:

```
tableData.tableDataList.filter(item => item.id !== rowId)
```

The full example must look something like this:

```
settableData(tData => {
  
  return tData.tableDataList.filter(item => item.id !== rowId);
});
```

Comment: Seems u got me wrong. The problem is - I am no able to access rowId.

Comment: Row buttons are suposed to be in a map? If its the case rowId cab be the index of the map

Comment: @Nacho I just cant access the rowId variable inside the setstate function. I don't know why it is not accessible.

Comment: @AnilPBabu I dont see why you should not be able to access the rowId inside the setState function, but you can try doing this, that should also work:

```const deleteRow = (rowId) => {
    const filteredTableData = tableData.tableDataList.filter(item => item.id !== rowId) 
    settableData(filteredTableData);
}
```